# How do you enable mysql.trace_mode for php?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I would like to have it so if there is a mysql error it throws a php style error.

From what I found, mysql.trace_mode is close to what I want.

But I can't enable this.

I added an error to mysql statement...but no complaints from php!

I've tried many variations...and nothing works:

```
.htaccess: php_flag mysql.trace_mode on
php.ini: mysql.trace_mode on
In my template header: ini_set('mysql.trace_mode', 1);
```

None of this works!  Am I missing something obvious here?

Yes, I'm using php 4.3+ (5.6.13)

As for a sample statement...here goes:

```
<?php echo $result = $dbconn->query("asdfsadf sadf); ?>
```

Php warnings are enabled and that works.

--

Problem solved.  Thanks Daan!

I was using mysqli...for anybody else who has this problem, just had this to your header:

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

Works very nicely...ideally it would come with a die command, but it still is nice.

Comment: How do you check if it's not enabled ? Aren't you using mysqli or PDO in your code ?

Comment: I ran a mysql statement (mysqli) with an obvious error.  The statement was definitely bad...but error was outputted?

Comment: `mysql.trace_mode` only applies to the mysql extension, not mysqli.

Comment: Did you enable display_errors and error_reporting?

Comment: "PHP *4.3+*"?! Can't you be more specific?

Comment: PHP 4.3 ? https://secure.php.net/releases/

Comment: @MarcB yes those are enabled.

Comment: My php version is 5.6.13

Comment: @deceze  You might be onto something...is there an equivalent for mysqli?  If you add your comment as an answer I'll upvote it...for what it is worth...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Comment: Daan...that did it!  Add an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql.trace_mode` is a [runtime configuration option for ***ext/mysql***](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.trace-mode), not mysqli. There is [no equivalent ini option for mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php); instead, [`mysqli_driver::$report_mode`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) seems to be the equivalent.

Comment: It says I don't have enough points to rep you...but thanks!  Daan's answer actually did the trick and I updated the original post for others who want to do this.  Just add to your php template header: mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);